# Xamarin xaml coding standarts

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, coding-style

I am self learner of Xamarin. I've started to lear it from Miscrosoft tutorial on their web site. And they suggest that the xaml code will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">

    <Button
        android:text="Add New Recepie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/generalAddButton"
        android:bufferType="normal" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recepeListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I look at some videos on Lynda.com the suggested code style is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Paperboy.Pages.ListViewPage1"
             Title="ListView">
  <ListView Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsGrouped}"
            ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
            ItemSelected="Handle_ItemSelected"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding Key}"
            IsGroupingEnabled="true"
            GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshDataCommand}">
    <ListView.Header>
      <StackLayout Padding="10" 
                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                   BackgroundColor="#dadada">
        <Label Text="Header"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <!--Built in Cells-->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"
                  Detail="{Binding Detail}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
```

Most difference is in binding between code and UI. Microsoft uses "+id/ID" notation and people from Lynda is using "x:ID" and "{Binding ID}" notation.
What is more correct / common / useful in the real world? Especially if I want to download some predefined UI xaml templates.

Comment: First one is AXML (Android-XML) and Second one is XAML (Xamarin-Extensible Application Markup Language or XAML)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is for **Xamarin Android** UI layout (which is NOT XAML), while your 2nd example is **Xamarin Forms** XAML.  These are two completely different things.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you for your answer! So in order for code to look like professional code I need to rewrite the first example as a second example, am I correct? (I mean all except main file and etc)

Comment: No.  They are completely different technologies.  They look different because the are different.